# How do I get the handle of a particular window that's open?

Tags: c++, window, handle

Firstly, I have very very limited knowledge of C++.

A couple of years ago I managed to cobble some code together that read a memory area of some fruit machine emulation software. It worked based on the fruit machine window title having the letters "DX" in it.

The code I used was as follows:

```
    if (strstr(lpszTitle, "DX") && !strstr(lpszTitle, "=")) {
        cout << "\nFound fruity with name: " << lpszTitle << "\n";
        currentWindowName = lpszTitle;

        // Found "DX" in the title of the window
        // so it must be an MFME window
        GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, &pid);
        HANDLE phandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_READ, 0, pid);

        if (!phandle)
        {
            cout << "\nCould not get handle!\n";
            soundHopperAlarm(5); // "Error, could not get window process handle"
            cin.get();
        }
        else
        { // rest of code here...
```

Back then someone told me that a better way of getting the window handle was this code:

```
wchar_t process[] = L"MFME.exe";
DWORD pid= GetPID(process);
HANDLE phandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_OPERATION | PROCESS_VM_READ, false, pid);
```

I didn't change my code because (at the time) it suited my purpose. I simply changed all the "fruit machines" I was emulating to have the text "DX" in their title and it worked fine...

However, I'm currently trying to add over 1,000 fruit machines to the system and it would be a LOT easier if there was a more robust method for get the window handle without having to alter every window title.

I can't really make sense of the new code and simply copying/pasteing into my existing code causes errors around GetPID being undefined so I wondered if someone could help me with a robust solution to get the handle of the window that's open by the "MFME.exe" software?

Any help/guidance very much appreciated.

Comment: See [Process Enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/process-enumeration) and [Enumerating All Processes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/psapi/enumerating-all-processes) on MSDN. But personally, rather than enumerating processes, I would enumerate windows, and just make sure that the fruit windows had a unique and consistent class name rather than a title, then you can use `FindWindow/Ex()` or `GetClassName()` to find them

Comment: @RemyLebeau thank you for your help and the links. I'll have a read through them today and see if I can get my head around it. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a process handle (a handle to the process with the permissions you desire, not a window HWND handle) you may need to run your program as administrator.  If you're running it from the VS debugger you will need to run the VS process as admin as well.

Here is some code using CreateToolHelp32Snapshot to enumerate the processes to get the correct one.

```cpp
#include <Windows.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>

DWORD GetProcId(const char* procName)
{
    DWORD procId = 0;
    HANDLE hSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
    if (hSnap != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        PROCESSENTRY32 procEntry;
        procEntry.dwSize = sizeof(procEntry);

        if (Process32First(hSnap, &procEntry))
        {
            do
            {
                if (!_stricmp(procEntry.szExeFile, procName))
                {
                    procId = procEntry.th32ProcessID;
                    break;
                }
            } while (Process32Next(hSnap, &procEntry));

        }
    }
    CloseHandle(hSnap);
    return procId;
}

int main()
{
    DWORD procId = GetProcId("MFME.exe");

    HANDLE hProc = 0;
    hProc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_OPERATION | PROCESS_VM_READ, false, procId);

    std::cout << std::hex << "0x" << hProc << std::endl;

    std::getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

This should fulfill your needs